# Как обернуть каждый элемент в контейнер jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мне нужно выбрать все элементы **a** обернуть кадлый из них в **li** и добавить в **ul** с **id="menu"** .

Делаю так, но не работает.

```js
$('#toplinks a').clone().wrap('<li>').appendTo('#menu');
```

```css
#toplinks a {
  display: block;
}

#menu li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="toplinks">
  <a>Главная</a>
  <a>Бланк заказа</a>
  <a>Прайс лист</a>
</p>

<ul id="menu">

</ul>
```

То есть a дублируются, но не оборачиваются в li (каждый из них).

Answer (score 2):

В справке по [функции `wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

> This method returns the original set of elements for chaining purposes.

> Этот метод возвращает оригинальный набор, для продолжения работы с ним.

Таким образом, делая после `wrap` -> `appendTo` в элемент добавляются клонированные ссылки, а не элементы `li`. Для исправления, добавлять нужно родителей текущих элементов. Их можно получить с помощью [функции `parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Пример:

```js
$('#toplinks a').clone().wrap('<li>').parent().appendTo('#menu');
```

```css
#toplinks a {
  display: block;
}

#menu li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="toplinks">
  <a>Главная</a>
  <a>Бланк заказа</a>
  <a>Прайс лист</a>
</p>

<ul id="menu">

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#toplinks a').clone().appendTo('#menu').wrap('<li></li>');
```

```css
#toplinks a {
  display: block;
}

#menu li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="toplinks">
  <a>Главная</a>
  <a>Бланк заказа</a>
  <a>Прайс лист</a>
</p>

<ul id="menu">

</ul>
```